# function type when used with decltype

Tags: c++, decltype, is-same

I was looking into `decltype` and `std::is_same_v` and tried them on functions.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t){}

template<typename T>
using f = decltype(func<T>);

template<typename T>
using ff = decltype((func<T>));

template<typename T>
using fff = void(*)(T);


template<typename T, typename U, typename Z>
void test(T t, U u, Z z){
   std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::boolalpha
             << std::is_same_v<T, U> << " "
             << std::is_same_v<U, Z> << " "
             << std::is_same_v<Z, T>;
}
int main()
{
    f<int> f1; // 1
    ff<int> ff1 = func<int>; // 2
    fff<int> fff1 = func<int>;

    test(f1, ff1, fff1);
    return 0;
}
```

[link to the demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWPsW9jxh)

Output:

```
void test(T, U, Z) [with T = void (*)(int); U = void (*)(int); Z = void (*)(int)]
true true true
```

While editing I removed parameter by mistake and ran the code. [link to the demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cETc65onz)

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename Z>
void test(T t, U u) // Z z is missing
{ // nothing changed in the body }
```

```
no matching function for call to 'test(void (&)(int), void (&)(int), void (*&)(int))'
   36 |     test(f1, ff1, fff1);
      |                       ^
```

It looks like `Z` is different type but `std::is_same_v<U, Z>` gives `true`. And I thought `ff` and `f` would be different types as per [`decltype` in cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus decltype(x) and decltype((x)) are often different types.

---

1. When I try to initialize `f f1 = func<int>;` I get a warning and an error.

```
 warning: declaration of 'void f1(int)' has 'extern' and is initialized
   32 |     f<int> f1 =func<int>;
      |            ^~
<source>:32:16: error: function 'void f1(int)' is initialized like a variable
   32 |     f<int> f1 =func<int>;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
```

2. When I don't initialize `ff ff1;` I get an error saying

```
error: 'ff1' declared as reference but not initialized
   33 |     ff<int> ff1 ;
      |             ^~~
```

As far as I know, I got reference type due to `decltype((func<T>))` but `std::is_same_v` gave `true` in `test`.

Apparenlty, `std::is_same_v` tells all three are same yet they are different. I'm a beginner in c++ and I'm not able to comprehend what's going.

Comment: Not a full answer, so posting as a comment. The diagnostic you got shows mismatching types [before the values decayed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay). Notice how [these decayed types](https://godbolt.org/z/n8erneoPq) match the output of those in your first example that compiles.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you. From question `ff` is a refernce type function pointer, `f` is a function pointer(not sure). Is it that always there are decayed just like arrays are decayed to pointer when passed to a function?

Comment: [Neither `ff` nor `f` are initially pointer types (though `fff` is)](https://godbolt.org/z/E58x7E5o7), `f` is a value type and `ff` is a reference type, but both decay to pointers when passed to `test()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you so much. Now it makes a lot more sense. I should have put `std::is_same_v` in the main itself. `std::is_same_v<void(int), f<int>>` -> `true`...`std::is_same_v<void(&)(int), ff<int>>` -> `true`...`std::is_same_v<void(*)(int), fff<int>>` -> `true`. I hope I got all the types correct. Please consider adding an answer. I'll accept it. Again thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: I don't understand the error given by `f f1 = func<int>;` what does it mean tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is similar to:

```
f<int> f1;                 // `void f1(int);`, function declaration
ff<int> ff1 = func<int>;   // `void (&ff1)(int) = func<int>;`, reference to function
fff<int> fff1 = func<int>; // `void (*fff1)(int) = &func<int>;` pointer to function,
                           // decay of `func<int>` to pointer
```

As C-array, you cannot pass function by value; they decay to pointer.

so

```
test(f1, ff1, fff1); // test(&f1, &ff1, fff1);
```

and inside test, all parameter have `void (*)(int)` type.

Comment: Thank you. What does this warning message mean? `declaration of 'void f1(int)' has 'extern' and is initialized`?

Comment: You cannot initialize a **function** `int f1(int) = /*..*/;`